# pyside: tcp server port parameter is disregarded?

Tags: tcp, pyside

I'm trying to establish TCP server on port number 502 - but cannot get it done in PySide.

My code :

```
self.tcpServer = QtNetwork.QTcpServer(self)
self.tcpServer.listen(QtNetwork.QHostAddress.Any,502)
```

but then

```
self.tcpServer.serverPort()
```

report port that is not 502. It seems that PySide is disregarding my port number 502.

Anyone has working example of this or any advice ?

Thanks in advance,
Bulek.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's related to your problem (I'm not familiar with PySide), but you must run your code as root if you want to bind to any port less than 1024.

Comment: That is not a problem, cause I tried with code for TCP socket from Python and it works... The problem begins when I use PySide TCP server...